# RecyclerView not displaying data 1 is working but other is not showing anything, any ideas?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview

Building Movie app , lost in the logic of why this recyclerview wouldn't show anything when another is implemented the same way and works.

There is defo an error just can't find it .Been looking at screen long time. Thanks in advance!!

XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    tools:context="com.example.mrmohammad.movies4u.DetailActivity"

    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:showIn="@layout/activity_detail">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                >


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_title_movie"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/tv_title_movie_margin_top_content_detail"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_rating"
                    android:padding="@dimen/tv_title_movie_padding_content_detail"
                    android:text="Harry Potter"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="21sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_release_year"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/tv_release_year_content_detail_rating"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_rating"
                    android:padding="@dimen/tv_title_movie_padding_content_detail"
                    android:text="2018"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_title_movie" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_rating"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/tv_release_year_content_detail_rating"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_rating"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_star_black_24dp"
                    android:padding="@dimen/tv_title_movie_padding_content_detail"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:text="8.9"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_release_year" />


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/llsynopsisbtn"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/tv_release_year_content_detail_rating"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_rating">


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_synopsis_label"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/bg_rating"
                        android:padding="@dimen/tv_title_movie_padding_content_detail"

                        android:text="@string/synopsis"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/emptyView"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_synopsis_label"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">


                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/share"
                            android:layout_width="35dp"
                            android:layout_height="35dp"
                            android:contentDescription="Share..."
                            android:padding="4dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_share_black_24dp" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/saveFav"
                            android:layout_width="35dp"
                            android:layout_height="35dp"
                            android:layout_below="@id/share"
                            android:contentDescription="Save in Favorites"
                            android:padding="4dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/thumbsup" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/deleteFav"
                            android:layout_width="35dp"
                            android:layout_height="35dp"

                            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/saveFav"
                            android:contentDescription="Delete from Favorites"
                            android:padding="4dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/delete" />


                    </LinearLayout>


                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_synopsis"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/synopsis_margin_left"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/synopsis_margin_right"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/synopsis_margin_top"

                    android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitationlaboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/llsynopsisbtn" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/thumbnailURL"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linLayContentDetail"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_synopsis">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/trailer"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/bg_rating"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:text="Trailers"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="20sp"


                        />

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/rvTrailers"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="3dp"
                        android:clipToPadding="false"
                        android:padding="12dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="25dp"
                        android:scrollbars="vertical"

                        >


                    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/linLayContentDetail">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/review"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/bg_rating"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:text="Reviews"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="20sp"


                        />

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/rvReview"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="3dp"
                        android:clipToPadding="false"
                        android:padding="12dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="25dp"


                        >

                        <!--HERE IS TEH RECYCLERVIEW THAT DONT DISPLAY-->




                    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

                </LinearLayout>


            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

DetailActivity:

```
    public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView movieName, releaseDate, userRating, synopsis;
    int id;
    ImageView iv, share, saveFav, deletFav;
    private RecyclerView rvDetail, rvReview;
    private TrailerAdapter adapter;
    private ReviewAdapter reviewAdapter;
    private List<Trailer> trailerList;
    private List<Review> reviewList;
    public static final String BASE_URL = 
    "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500";


    public static final String TAG = DetailActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    public MovieDbHelper dbHelper;
    private Movie favoriteMovie;
    private AppCompatActivity activity = DetailActivity.this;
    String poster, overview, rating, movieTitle, release;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
        Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this);


        share = findViewById(R.id.share);
        saveFav = findViewById(R.id.saveFav);
        deletFav = findViewById(R.id.deleteFav);


        final int movie_id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");

        if (checkFavoriteMovie(movie_id)) {

            //Is a favorite
            saveFav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            saveFav.setEnabled(false);

            deletFav.setEnabled(true);
            deletFav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        } else {
            deletFav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            deletFav.setEnabled(false);
            saveFav.setEnabled(true);
            saveFav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }


        iv = findViewById(R.id.iv_detail);
        movieName = findViewById(R.id.tv_title_movie);
        releaseDate = findViewById(R.id.tv_release_year);
        userRating = findViewById(R.id.tv_rating);
        synopsis = findViewById(R.id.tv_synopsis);

        Intent intentFromAdapter = getIntent();
        if (intentFromAdapter.hasExtra("original_title")) {
            poster = 
        intentFromAdapter.getExtras().getString("poster_path");
            movieTitle = 
        intentFromAdapter.getExtras().getString("original_title");
            overview = intentFromAdapter.getExtras().getString("overview");
            rating = 
        intentFromAdapter.getExtras().getString("vote_average");
            release = 
        intentFromAdapter.getExtras().getString("release_date");

            Picasso.with(this).load(BASE_URL + poster).into(iv);
            movieName.setText(movieTitle);
            releaseDate.setText(release);
            userRating.setText(rating);
            synopsis.setText(overview);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Data...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = 
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);


        saveFav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if (checkFavoriteMovie(movie_id)) {


                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Already added!", 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {


                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = 

getSharedPreferences("com.example.mrmohammad.movies4u.DetailActivity", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("Favorite Added", true);
                    editor.commit();
                    addFavorites();
                    Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this, "Movie Added successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
//

                saveFav.setEnabled(false);
                deletFav.setEnabled(true);
                deletFav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                saveFav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//


            }
        });

        deletFav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("com.example.mrmohammad.movies4u.DetailActivity", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putBoolean("Favorite Removed", true);
                editor.commit();

                removeFromFavorites(movie_id);
                Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this, "Movie Removed...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


//


                deletFav.setEnabled(false);
                saveFav.setEnabled(true);
                deletFav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                saveFav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


//
            }

        });

        share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String d = movieName.getText().toString().trim();
                String s = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + d;
                s = s.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
                String full = "CLICK LINK " + s;

                Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(DetailActivity.this)
                        .setType("text/plain")
                        .setText(full)
                        .getIntent();
                startActivity(shareIntent);
            }
        });


        initializeViews();


    }


    private void initializeViews() {

        /////// Trailers

        trailerList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new TrailerAdapter(this, trailerList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        rvDetail = findViewById(R.id.rvTrailers);
        rvDetail.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        rvDetail.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        ////////// Reviews

        reviewList = new ArrayList<>();
        reviewAdapter = new ReviewAdapter(this, reviewList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager lm = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        rvReview = findViewById(R.id.rvReview);
        rvReview.setLayoutManager(lm);
        rvReview.setAdapter(reviewAdapter);
        reviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        loadJSONTrailers();
        loadJSONReview();


    }


    private void loadJSONTrailers() {
        int movie_id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");
        try {
            if (BuildConfig.THE_MOVIE_DB_API_TOKEN.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please obtain API KEY", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            Client Client = new Client();
            Service apiService = Client.getClient().create(Service.class);
            Call<TrailerResponse> call = apiService.getMovieTrailer(movie_id, BuildConfig.THE_MOVIE_DB_API_TOKEN);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<TrailerResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<TrailerResponse> call, Response<TrailerResponse> response) {
                    List<Trailer> trailers = response.body().getResuts();
                    rvDetail.setAdapter(new TrailerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), trailers));
                    rvDetail.smoothScrollToPosition(0);

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<TrailerResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("Error", t.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this, "Error fetching Trailer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Error", e.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void loadJSONReview() {
        int movie_id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");

        try {
            if (BuildConfig.THE_MOVIE_DB_API_TOKEN.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please obtain API KEY", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;

            }
            Client Client = new Client();
            Service apiService = Client.getClient().create(Service.class);
            Call<ReviewResponse> call = apiService.getMovieReviews(movie_id, BuildConfig.THE_MOVIE_DB_API_TOKEN);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<ReviewResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ReviewResponse> call, Response<ReviewResponse> response) {
                    List<Review> reviews = response.body().getResults();
                    rvReview.setAdapter(new ReviewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), reviews));
                    rvReview.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Here>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ReviewResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("Error", t.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this, "Error fetching Review", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Error", e.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void addFavorites() {


        int movie_id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");

        dbHelper = new MovieDbHelper(activity);
        favoriteMovie = new Movie();

        String rate = getIntent().getExtras().getString("vote_average");
        String poster = getIntent().getExtras().getString("poster_path");


        favoriteMovie.setId(movie_id);
        favoriteMovie.setOriginalTitle(movieName.getText().toString().trim());
        favoriteMovie.setPosterPath(poster);
        favoriteMovie.setVoteAverage(Double.parseDouble(rate));
        favoriteMovie.setOverview(synopsis.getText().toString().trim());
        favoriteMovie.setReleaseDate(releaseDate.getText().toString().trim());


        dbHelper.addFavorites(favoriteMovie);
        Log.d(TAG, "Added fav.....");


    }

    private void removeFromFavorites(int id) {


        getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().delete(MovieContract.MovieEntry.CONTENT_URI, MovieContract.MovieEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
    }

    private boolean checkFavoriteMovie(int id) {
        Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(MovieContract.MovieEntry.CONTENT_URI, null, MovieContract.MovieEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_ID + " = " + id, null, null);
        assert cursor != null;
        if (cursor.getCount() <= 0) {
            cursor.close();
            return false;
        }
        cursor.close();
        return true;
    }


}

ReviewAdapter


    public class ReviewAdapter extends 
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ReviewAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Review> reviewsList;


    public ReviewAdapter(Context mContext, List<Review> reviewsList){


        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.reviewsList = reviewsList;
    }

    @Override
    public ReviewAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i){
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.review, viewGroup, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(view);

    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ReviewAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int i){
        holder.reviewAuthor.setText(reviewsList.get(i).getAuthor());
        holder.reviewContent.setText(reviewsList.get(i).getContent());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        return reviewsList.size();

    }
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView reviewAuthor;
        TextView reviewContent;


        public MyViewHolder(View view){
            super(view);
            reviewAuthor = view.findViewById(R.id.review_author);
            reviewContent = view.findViewById(R.id.review_content);



            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                    if(pos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                        String author = reviewsList.get(pos).getAuthor();
                        String content  = reviewsList.get(pos).getContent();

                        reviewAuthor.setText(author);
                        reviewContent.setText(content);

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Any advice greatly Appreciated my issues are that the recyclerview isnt displaying no data however it does show them with the endpoints in the JSON. I can link my github aswell but you'll need to get [another API KEY from here](https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api) .

My github link is [here](https://github.com/BenMohammad/Movies4U-master)

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried adding fixed `android:layout_height` for your RecyclerView?

Comment: Yeah makes no difference.

I'm working on this now.
Thanks

Comment: tried this again at 300dp and it . shows thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that your `RecyclerView` height is evaluated as "zero".

In order to debug this you can set fixed `android:layout_height` to some bigger fixed value.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to put a **listView** or any view similar to a listView inside a **scrollview** or any view similar to scrollview.

The consequence might be that only the first element in the list will be displayed. The rest will be stack behind that first item.

Comment: whats the alternative?